# ParcelJS rebuilds only once

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

I'm using ParcelJS (the most recent - 1.4.1 version) in my pet project with basic configuration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ParcelJS should rebuild my project's files after every change by default. It does, but... only once. After first change it rebuilds changed files, but it's last rebuild. 
Has anyone similar problem? Do you how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also met this problem.

this is because the **IDE Settings**, you only need to shut down [safety writing].

Here are related issues [enter link description here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/221)

Answer (score 0):

On VS Code, zhangyuhan2016's answer is not the solution because VS Code does not use atomic file writes.

In 2020, on WSL2 (Windows subsystem for Linux), the solution for me was to move the root directory of the project to somewhere in the Linux path (so not in /mnt/*).

Check here for more info:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4417